# does finally block always run in generator?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

in sqlalchemy i make use of sessions  in the following manner:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, sessionmaker

from app.core.config import get_settings

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = get_settings().DB_URL
engine = create_async_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
    future=True,
    echo=get_settings().DB_DEBUG,
    pool_size=get_settings().CONNECTION_POOL_SIZE,
    pool_pre_ping=True,
)

async_session = sessionmaker(
    engine,
    expire_on_commit=False,
    class_=AsyncSession,
)


async def get_session() -> Session:
    session: Session = async_session()
    try:
        yield session
    finally:
        await session.close()
```

along time after i run the above code, i get an error which is a timeout for getting a connection from connection pool. i run out of connections if i don't return connection ( with closing it) to connection pool. my question is in the above code in the get_session function, does for every connection finally block gets run?( i.e every connection finally returns to pool)

Answer (score 0):

If your sessions are being kept open, then it means that the generators that created them are being kept alive and running.

The generator needs to finish its execution, be closed, or be GC'd for the finally to run. If you're not iterating through it whole for it to finish its execution, you should be closing the generator to prevent it from keeping the session for longer than necessary.

As an example for the GC and close, the following code

```py
def generator_func():
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        print("Ran finally cleanup")

generator = generator_func()
next(generator)
print("deleting generator")
del generator
print("deleted generator")
print()
generator = generator_func()
next(generator)
print("closing generator")
generator.close()
print("closed generator")
```

gives you this output

```
deleting generator
Ran finally cleanup
deleted generator

closing generator
Ran finally cleanup
closed generator
```

To ensure the close is run, [`contextlib.closing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing) can be used for clsing the generator through a context manager.

This also leads back to your `Session` object, which [seems to be a context manager](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker) by itself and should be used as one if possible.